# Which version control systems (VCS) allow overlaying mapping?

Tags: version-control

What version control software allowing overlaying branches similar to [Perforce views](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/views.html)?

An overlay mapping is used to map files from more than one depot directory into the same place in the workspace.

For example each branch has several fixes and need to be brought together into the Project/Source directory.

**Perforce example:**

```
//depot/Project/Source/...   //workspace/Project/Source/...
+//depot/branch1/Source/...  //workspace/Project/Source/...
+//depot/branch2/Source/...  //workspace/Project/Source/...
+//depot/branch3/Source/file.java  //workspace/Project/Source/file.java
```

Comment: Would [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) match this requirement?

Comment: Surely if you have 2 or more files with the same name you are going to have a problem - it would be better to merge the branches, (unless I am not getting the hang of what is supposed to be going on). Otherwise you are just cherry picking to create a local only branch.

Comment: With overlaying you can lay a branch on top of another and commit to the overlaying branch only not effecting the underlying branch. In the example `branch3/Source/file.java` would be change not the `Project/Source/file.java`